# Call a smart contract payable function sending erc20 token

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, payable

We can send a er20 token to a smart contract.

To track it we can use a `function`  ( msg.value is always wei )

But how do i verify if the erc20 token is actually sent ?

For example i want to set map true if the person sent > 5 `vbcoins`

```
function sendVBCoins(uint256 _howmuch){
  require(_howmuch >= 5);
  goodperson[msg.sender] = true;
}
```

Anyone can send 1 wei and call that function and become `goodperson`.

How do i solve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This sort of transfer can be done in two stages.

The person who aspires to be good needs to first call `vbToken.approve(<your contract's address>, 5)` (or rather `5 * 10**decimals`). This authorizes your contract to take 5 vbcoins from them.

They then call `sendVBCoins(5)` (or, again, more likely `5 * 10**decimals`). Inside `sendVBCoins`, you will call `vbToken.transferFrom(msg.sender, _howmuch)`. If that succeeds, then you've received those vbcoins from them, and you can consider them to be a "good person."