# Sending token with contract interaction in Remix

Tags: remix, tokens, erc-20, chainlink, transfer

I'm aware of using the value field in Remix to include ETH with my function call transaction but is there a way to send another token with my transaction, for example, LINK?

Additionally I would like to require there's a certain amount of LINK sent, similar to require(msg.value == X) for ETH. I already have the token interface imported and initialized but am unsure where to go from there and don't know how to send the token in Remix to test it anyway.

```
import "https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink/blob/develop/evm-contracts/src/v0.6/interfaces/LinkTokenInterface.sol";
LinkTokenInterface internal LINK;
//in constructor (kovan LINK token)
LINK = LinkTokenInterface(0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, but the flow is a little counter-intuitive and takes some getting used to.

You can send ETH and/or data to a contract function. The data can instruct a contract function to seize a certain amount of a token from someone, usually the msg.sender (but not necessarily).

Your contract would use the ERC20, `transferFrom(<funder>, <amount>)` function. Since we can't have everyone just helping themselves to everyone else's money, the user first approves an allowance with the `approve(<yourContract>, <agreedAmount>)` function or the `increaseAllowance()` function.

e.g.

```
token = LinkTokenInterface(0xa36085F69e2889c224210F603D836748e7dC0088)
...
token.transferFrom(msg.sender, msg.value);
```

- Alice => ERC20 "let the contract have my tokens"
- Alice => contract "take my tokens"
- contract => ERC20 "give me alice's tokens"

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

Think I found the answer actually:
[Call a smart contract payable function sending erc20 token](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/32644/call-a-smart-contract-payable-function-sending-erc20-token?rq=1)

User/me first needs to call the approve function in the LINK contract then my Remix contract can transfer tokens from msg.sender to itself itself using LINK's transferFrom function.

Comment: Yes. That's it.